# How communicate form inputs values in component with some controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i have this simple form in a EmberComponent:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/booking-box">
 <form>
  <label for="name"> First Name </label>
  <input id="name" type="text" />

  <input type="submit" value="Send" {{action 'send' }}/>
 </form>
</script>
```

And i have the JS:

```
SiteApp.BookingBoxComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
 actions: {
   send: function() {
     // crazy logic to manipulate the HTML
   }
 }
});
```

The form is very simple, but i'm manipulating the html of the form after send the name, that's why i need a component. The code for manipulate the html is not relevant here, right? That's why i'm not going to past.

And i have the controller:

```
SiteApp.BookingController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  create: function() {
    // I want access name here, is possible??
  }
});
```

Is possible access the value of the input name in the BookingController? And more important, how could i trigger the create method of the BookingController??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `this.sendAction`, see http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/components/handling-events/#toc_sending-actions

For example:

*app/templates/booking.hbs*

```
{{booking-box action="create"}}
```

*app/templates/components/booking-box.hbs*

```
<form {{action "send" on="submit"}}>
  <label for="name">First Name</label>
  {{input name="name" id="name" value=name type="text"}}
  {{input type="submit" value="Send"}}
</form>
```

*app/components/booking-box.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    send: function() {
      this.sendAction("action", this.get("name"));
    }
  }
});
```

*app/controllers/booking.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    create(name) {
      console.log(name);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Ashley, could you help me with other problem? I'm using this BookingBoxComponent in the index template, so i just have access to the IndexController. Is possible fix this issue?

Comment: It may be possible, but it's not really the ember way of doing it, AFAIK. Actions should bubble up, so if it's being used on the index page you should probably put the action in Application Controller or Route.